# Excel countif cell range contains specific instances of full stop

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I need to count how many cells from a range that has for an examples 4 dots in the string.

[image: This is column A]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF and wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*.*.*.*.*")
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201324/discussion-on-answer-by-bigben-excel-countif-cell-range-contains-specific-instan).